# httpc request: Bad argument exception length

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I´ve a problem to make a httpc request to my Java servlet.
On my local system, the code is working fine, but if I execute the call from an erlang file of the ejabberd server, I get a bad argument exception.

This is my code from my local system:

`Body = "deviceToken=dy....[Very long FCM token]....b1&sender=epeued7o3z",
  inets:start(),
  httpc:request(post,
    {
    "http://192.168.2.110:8080/020/service", [],
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Body
    }, [], []).`

I copied the code to the erlang file of the ejabberd server and I got this exception:

`2017-11-24 18:05:40 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: httpc_handler:init/1
    pid: <0.522.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: bad argument: [{erlang,length,[[100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,<<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61|<<"epeued7o3z">>]],[]},{httpc_request,body_length,1,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,233}]},{httpc_request,post_data,4,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,208}]},{httpc_request,send,4,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,85}]},{httpc_handler,connect_and_send_first_request,3,[{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,815}]},{httpc_handler,init,1,[{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,238}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]
    ancestors: [httpc_handler_sup,httpc_sup,inets_sup,<0.439.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []
    links: [<0.445.0>,#Port<0.14269>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 978
  neighbours:
2017-11-24 18:05:40 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,httpc_handler_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {badarg,[{erlang,length,[[100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,<<"dy...[Very long FCM token].....Kn4b1">>,38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61|<<"epeued7o3z">>]],[]},{httpc_request,body_length,1,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,233}]},{httpc_request,post_data,4,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,208}]},{httpc_request,send,4,[{file,"httpc_request.erl"},{line,85}]},{httpc_handler,connect_and_send_first_request,3,[{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,815}]},{httpc_handler,init,1,[{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,238}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.522.0>},{id,undefined},{mfargs,{httpc_handler,start_link,undefined}},{restart_type,temporary},{shutdown,4000},{child_type,worker}]`

Is it right that the body length is wrong / to long, because on my local program it is working well? The request to the servlet should not be the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exception error: bad argument:
[{erlang,length,[
    [100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,
     <<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,
     38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61|<<"epeued7o3z">>]
    ]                             ^
                                  |
 This create an improper list that make the function length/1 fail.
```

You have defined an improper list, because the last term, after the cons operator: `<<"epeued7o3z">>`  is a binary, not a list.

You can solve this by writting:

```
[100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,
 <<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,
 38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61,
 <<"epeued7o3z">>
]
```

or

```
[100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,
 <<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,
 38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61|"epeued7o3z"
]
```

The call to length/1 will return the length of the iolist, note that the lengths are different, the first list length is 22, while the second one is 31.

If you need a flat list rather than an iolist, I don't know any function that make it directly, but you can convert the iolist to a binary first, and then convert the binary into a list (and the length is now 65):

```
1> IoList = [100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,<<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,38,115,101,110,100,101,114,61,<<"epeued7o3z">>].
[100,101,118,105,99,101,84,111,107,101,110,61,
 <<"dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1">>,38,115,101,110,
 100,101,114,61,<<"epeued7o3z">>]
2> binary_to_list(iolist_to_binary(IoList)).
"deviceToken=dy....[Very long FCM token]...Kn4b1&sender=epeued7o3z"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because it's attempting to call `erlang:length/1`, which expects a list, on a value that appears to be an iolist (a mixture of nested lists and binaries).

Are you certain that your snippet accurately shows how you're constructing `Body`?

Comment: Yes, I´m sure with the construction of the "Body". My Java servlet is able to extract the values "deviceToken" and "sender" from the request.